# What page event can I pass values to user control?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

Which page life cycle event can I use to pass parameters to user controls that are embedded in the front-end markup? I don't want to load them programmatically, I just want to pass parameters to the ones I dragged on to the page.

Comment: Your question is vague - post your relevant code, describe what you're trying to do, post your attempted solutions and describe where they fall short.

Comment: `Page_Load` should do the trick.  Do you have an example of an attempt which failed in some way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Page_Load` event could be a good place to do that. Here's a nice article explaining in details the page lifecycle in ASP.NET and for what purposes you could use the various events and at what stage they are raised: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx